# Как можно убрать процесс из диспетчера задач Windows Vista?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Вожусь тут с одной программой, прочитал море чего и так и не смог понять? как убрать процесс из диспетчера задач. (

Значит, что я понял:

1. Существует область в памяти, которая вроде как обновляется. Эта область содержит процессы (запущенные).
2. Существует несколько способов изьятия процесса из таск манаджера, мне подходит тот, который как бы "перехватывает" эту область памяти и возвращает диспетчеру подкорректированный список процессов.

Значит проблема: rучу кодов написано на дельфи, а я с ним не дружу... Та куча, которая с++ не работает...

Помогите нормальным кодом, рессурсом, примером....

Answer (score 2):

Убрать можно перехватив соответсвующие функции. Менеджер процессов получает список, вызывая NtQuerySystemInformation. Она в свою очередь является оберткой к вызову функции ядра Windows.

По поводу перехвата:

[Перехват вызовов API-функций](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/90377/)

[Методы перехвата API-вызовов в Win32](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/apicallsintercepting.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Используй командную строку `Windows, taskkill`.

Как использовать данную команду, можно легко понять по хелпу (`taskkill /?`).